# select / join / t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, join

I have two tables

```
NumberOfTeam    NameOfTeam
1               Roma
2               Manchester
3               Inter
4               Milan

Game    FirstTeam   GoalsFirstTeam  SecondTeam  GoalsSecondTeam
1       1           1               2           3
2       3           0               4           0
```

I need table like this:

```
Game    FirstTeam   GoalsFirstTeam  SecondTeam  GoalsSecondTeam
1       Roma        1               Manchester  3
2       Inter       0               Milan       0
```

Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: Please restate question: use Table 1: field, field, field; and Table 2: field, field, field    and I think you want a query that will give you results not another table.

Comment: Show us the query you've tried, and describe how it didn't produce what you were looking for. Demonstrate that you've put *some* effort into solving on your own.

Comment: Learn basic SQL, this is a good place to start: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @HoneyBadger - [No, that's an awful place to start](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Jamiec - It looked okay for basics to me. You link says too: "For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience". There are definitly better resources, that is true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your first table is called `Teams` and the second `Games`:

```
SELECT g.Game,
        t1.NameOfTeam AS FirstTeam,
        g.GoalsFirstTeam,
        t2.NameOfTeam AS SecondTeam,
        g.GoalsSecondTeam
FROM Games g
INNER JOIN Team t1 ON g.FirstTeam = t1.NumberOfTeam
INNER JOIN Team t2 ON g.SecondTeam = t2.NumberOfTeam
```